# Django and getting info from query string using handlers

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm a little lost with the best way to process a record from a displayed list. I'm allowing users to click on a link which will contain the record id in the querystring in the following way in my template.html:

```
<a href="/edit_record?id={{company.key.id}}">Edit</a>
```

I have in my handler:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', DisplayMaphandler),
  ('/companyadd', AddCompanyHandler),
  ('/validatecompanies', Validationhandler),
  ('/addcompanycategories', AddCompanyCategoriesHandler),
  ('/editcompany', EditCompanyHandler),
  ('/edit_record', EditRecordHandler),
], debug=True)
```

and I wish to get at the id, however this code is clearly wrong and does not work at all:

```
class EditRecordHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):    
    def get(request):
        myid = request.GET.get('id', '')
        self.response.out.write(myid)
```

How should I get at the id from this class. Plus I saw some things on urlconf, do I need to use such a thing. I know this class is triggered when clicking on a link but want to find the smartest way of making this work with the RequestHandler rather than a def function. The error I'm getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'EditRecordHandler' object has no attribute 'GET'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `EditRecordHandler` `get` method in something like this:

```
class EditRecordHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):    
    def get(self):
        myid = self.request.get('id')
        self.response.out.write(myid)
```

Comment: obvious...when you think. Thanks though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please fell free to edit ..

**in urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/edit_record/', EditRecordHandler),
)
```

**use request.method == 'GET'** and you forget (self,request):

```
class EditRecordHandler():    
    def get(self,request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            myid = self.request.get('id')
```